# CSS : centering a fixed menu with no specific width

Tags: html, css, menu

i've been struggling with something: centering my CSS menu!! i can't figure out how to do it. What am i doing wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/yfVs2/

Comment: menus are already centered. what you exactly want?

Comment: for it to be at the top of the page, and the whole menu "box" in the middle if the page...

Comment: please state the exact problem and post your reevant code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used position fixed. So the margin auto doesn't work with fixed position. You can do the following:

1. Remove the fixed positioning. Wrap in a div and assign width 100%.
2. Set width for you `ul`. If you want you `ul` to increase as `li` increases, you can set `ul` width to inherit.
3. If you still cant do it, make a comment and I will upload the code for you. But I am sure you can do it yourself.

Comment: bam! right there! out of the box thinking: i'm likin' it =) Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
.menu {
    height: 80px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    position: fixed;
    top: -8px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -200px; /* half of the .menu width if you don't know width delete this line */
}
```

And if you're not going to know the width of this element you can dynamically calculate it with javascript/jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var wdth = $('.menu').width();
    wdth = wdth/2;
    $('.menu').css('margin-left', -wdth);
});
```

Here is the working example http://jsfiddle.net/yfVs2/11/

Answer (score 0):

may be because of you have used `float:left`.